# Фантомный комментарий

Tags: дефект, комментарии

В [удалённом вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624244/178988) отображается сообщение

[image: Для удалённых/заблокированных сообщений/обзоров комментарии отключены | показать ещё 1 комментарий]

но при клике на <kbd>показать ещё 1 комментарий</kbd> комментарий не появляется:

[image: комментарий не появляется]

Остаются те же 5 комментариев, что и были.

Comment: По-моему что-то было раньше такое

Comment: @alexolut, если не путаю, его в тот раз случайно пофиксили...

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, почистили другое. Посмотрите в моих последних вопросах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin так [это](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4222/176217) дубликат, получается.